# If I change my VS Code extension's name, will I lose the downloads statistics?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

There's [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stevejpurves.cucumber). I'm the new maintainer of it and I want to update the extension's name, description, logo and publisher meta data (located in `package.json`).

If I do that, will I lose the marketplace's downloads and stars statistics? I'm afraid I might lose it, because the unique identifier (`publisher`.`extension_name`) would change.

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some experiementing:

- Update extension name (through display name): fine
- Updating other minor extension details: fine
- Updating name: fails [image]
- Updating publisher: fails

[image]

So in answer to your question, **no**, you can't update your publisher while still preserving download count.  You have three options:

A. Stay with same publisher, change display name.

B. Start new extension from scratch.  Add code in the original extension that displays a info message redirecting to the new one and you should get most of your downloads back.

C. contact marketplace support and ask them for a new copy feature (*good luck*)

I should note that you can add users to your publisher, so if you want to publish under a different account that is possible, just not changing the publisher itself.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In the end, I updated everything except publisher and extension name. What matters to the user is the display name, and that one you can freely change.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Almenon 's answer.

You can technically change the publisher ID and maintain the download stats by sending an email to the VS Marketplace support team and asking them to transfer the extension to a new publisher ID that you own.

Here is the reply I received on the matter:

> The download stats would remain same even after the extension transfer. Usually, we do not allow transfer of VSCode extensions since it has following consequences:
>
> 1. Users will not be able to install the older versions of your extensions that got published before the extension transfer from the VSCode.
> 2. If this extension is used as a dependency in other extensions by using publisherName.ExtensionName, that would not work.
> 3. You need to update all references to this extension with the new publisherName.

**The same does not apply for changing the extension name**